# How to test a logit model in R?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, logit

I'm building a logit model using R and I'm getting a result of 88.9% of accuracy (verified using the ROC [in rattle, evaluation tab] using 30% of my 34k dataset).

What kind of tests would be interesting to do to certify myself that it's a good model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should plot your residuals vs. explanatory variables (i.e. $X_i$'s) and residuals vs. fitted values to see if there is anything wrong with the model. There are other diagnostic plots. In R you can use function glm.diag.plots in package [boot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf). See the code below and also [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23666/explanation-of-r-diagnostic-plot-for-logistic-regression). Here I will also use package [Mass](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/MASS.pdf) to load a data.

```
library(MASS)
data(menarche) 
plot(Menarche/Total ~ Age, data=menarche)
glm.out = glm(cbind(Menarche, Total-Menarche) ~ Age,family=binomial(logit), data=menarche)
library(boot)
glm.diag.plots(glm.out)
```

[image]

And to have some more fun with the fitted values:

```
plot(Menarche/Total ~ Age, data=menarche)
lines(menarche$Age, glm.out$fitted, type="l", col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, another question rises, should the residuals be closer or far to each other? Should I try some manipulation in my variable to fix something I saw, like combining variables?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29271/interpreting-residual-diagnostic-plots-for-glm-models) and the links in the answer. It is much more comprehensive than what I was going to say here. Depending on the problem, you need to revised your model, sometimes removing a variable, sometimes transforming it. I cannot provide a single remedy, it is depends to the problem.